# Solving equations involving permutations and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to solve for $n$ if $$P^n_4=60\times C^n_2$$I’ve gotten up to $$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=30n(n-1)$$

Comment: simplify n(n-1) on both sides, you get (n-2)(n-3)=30, which leads to solution n=8 (or n=-3, which i suppose makes no sense because you are working with n positive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your equation can be simplified to

$n(n-1)[(n-2)(n-3)-30]=0$
which can be further simplified to

$n(n-1)[n^2-5n-24]=0$

From here we get following values

$n=-3,0,1,8$

Now since $n\geq4$

$n=8$ is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By eliminating common terms on both sides, you get $(n-2)(n-3)=30$, or $n^2-5n-24=0$.  Positive solution is $n=8$.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there! You got$$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=30n(n-1)$$Now shift all the terms to one side to get$$n(n-1)\Big[(n-2)(n-3)-30\Big]=0$$So $n$ could be $0,1$ or such that$$(n-2)(n-3)-30=0\\\implies n^2-5n-24=(n-8)(n+3)=0\\\therefore n=0,1,-3,8$$If you define $P^n_4=\displaystyle\frac{n!}{(n-4)!}$, you need $n\ge4$. This leaves you with the answer $n=8$.